# xslt Merge children of 2 parents and Store in a variable

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I receive an xml input like this:

```
  <root>
    <Tuple1>
      <child11></child11>
      <child12></child12>
      <child13></child13>
    </Tuple1>
    <Tuple1>
      <child11></child11>
      <child12></child12>
    </Tuple1>

    <Tuple2>
      <child21></child21>
      <child22></child22>
    </Tuple2>
    <Tuple2>
      <child21></child21>
      <child22></child22>
      <child23></child23>
    </Tuple2>
  </root>
```

How can I **merge the children** of each Tuple1 with children of Tuple2 and **store them in a variable** that will be used in the rest of xslt document? 
First tuple1 will be merged with first Tuple2 and second Tuple1 will be merged with 2nd Tuple2 and so on. The merged output that should be stored in variable would look like this in memory:

```
<root>
    <Tuple1>
      <child11></child11>
      <child12></child12>
      <child13></child13>

      <child21></child21>
      <child22></child22>
    </Tuple1>
    <Tuple1>
      <child11></child11>
      <child12></child12>

      <child21></child21>    
      <child22></child22>
      <child23></child23>
    </Tuple1>
  </root>
```

Is variable the best option? If we use variable, is it created once or it is created every time called?
I use xslt 3.0 so solution for any version can help.
Thanks and I appreciate your help)

Comment: Well, process all `Tuple1` elements with `for-each` or `apply-templates` for instance and then use the `position()` (`<xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>`) to copy the children of the relevant `Tuple2` (`<xsl:copy-of select="../Tuple2[position() = $pos]/*"/>`). Whether you do that for a variable or directly for the output tree does not make any difference in XSLT 2 or 3.

Comment: The use of a variable and the implementation strategy is up to the XSLT processor, but I am pretty sure that most will evaluate a variable only once when used first. Or, as you use XSLT 3 where Saxon is kind of the reference implementation, I think that is what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a minimal XSLT 3 approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
     <xsl:variable name="temp1">
         <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="Tuple1"/>
         </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:variable>
     <xsl:copy-of select="$temp1"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Tuple1">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="*, let $pos := position() return ../Tuple2[$pos]/*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Online at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqg, I have used XPath's `let` instead of XSLT's `xsl:variable` to store the position to access the specific `Tuple2`.