# Copying different elements into a variable based on a logic - XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-3.0

Well I guess this question is gonna be a bit challnging but I'll appreicate any help. 
I have an xml that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<root xmlns:cd="http://blabla" xmlns:se="http://blahblah">

  <se:Tuple>
    <se:name>AAA</se:name>
    <se:game>a</se:game>
  </se:Tuple>

  <se:Tuple>
    <se:name>BBB</se:name>
    <se:game>b</se:game>
  </se:Tuple>

  <se:Tuple>
    <se:name>CCC</se:name>
    <se:game>c</se:game>
  </se:Tuple>

  <cd:Tuple>
    <cd:name>AAA</cd:name>
    <cd:genre>aaa</cd:genre>
  </cd:Tuple>

  <cd:Tuple>
    <cd:name>CCC</cd:name>
    <cd:genre>ccc</cd:genre>
  </cd:Tuple>

</root>
```

I want to transform (mix) this data using xslt 3.0 and store it in a variable for further use in the xslt file:

```
  <se:Tuple>
    <se:name>AAA</se:name>
    <se:game>a</se:game>
    <cd:genre>aaa</cd:genre>
  </se:Tuple>

  <se:Tuple>
    <se:name>BBB</se:name>
    <se:game>b</se:game>
  </se:Tuple>

  <se:Tuple>
    <se:name>CCC</se:name>
    <se:game>c</se:game>
    <cd:genre>ccc</cd:genre>
  </se:Tuple>
```

The logic behind the mix is:
copy all se:Tuple to the variable. While copying each se:Tuple if there was any cd:Tuple that its cd:name is equal to se:name, copy the cd:genre from that Tuple into the se:Tuple too.

Huge thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a very straightforward join problem, for example

```
<xsl:template match="se:Tuple">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="../cd:Tuple[cd:name=current()/se:name]/cd:genre"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a simple grouping or cross-reference problem, depending on whether there can be `cd:Tuple` with `cd:name` that is not in any `se:Tuple`. If there aren't any then you can simply group `<xsl:for-each-group select="se:Tuple, cd:Tuple" group-by="se:name, cd:name">`, otherwise use a key `<xsl:key name="cd-tuple-ref" match="cd:Tuple" use="cd:name"/>` and then process any `se:Tuple` and copy `key('cd-tuple-ref', se:name)/cd:genre`.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to xslt, do you have the possibility to sort this in code? I'll  very much appreciate it.

Comment: Well, you have an example of the variable stuff in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51495405/252228, so using the key with `key('cd-tuple-ref', se:name)/cd:genr` instead of `let $pos := position() return ../Tuple2[$pos]/*` seems something you could try and experiment with on your own and then, if it really doesn't work out, tell us with the code you have tried in your question or another one where you are stuck exactly, i.e. which code you have, which result you want and which one you get or which error exactly you can't resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to responses from Martin Honnen and Michael Kay, the following code worked for me.

```
    <xsl:template match="se:Tuple">
         <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
             <xsl:copy-of select="../cd:Tuple[cd:name=current()/se:name]/cd:genre"/>
         </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:variable name="temp1">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="se:Tuple"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$temp1"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

I hope there are no typing mistakes as my own element names are different.